# Modifying the core tracker module

Tags: 7

I would like to modify the styling of the tracker module and also move it's content from a separate user profile tab to the main tab. What is the best way to accomplish this? Modifying the core module would be a bad idea right? I may also want to edit the module to change functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the best to clone the module, rename it to let's say "custom_tracker" and there do the modifications you need.

As I did this few times with other modules, here are some tips:

1. Rename with "custom" prefix/suffix to avoid name clashes. Don't forget to rename all function and variable (I mean the stored ones) names as well as all the files (tracker.module => custom_tracker.module)
2. Test the module in local before using it on the live site.
3. As the module isn't too big, I suggest reading all code and do the renaming manually. It's better than simple replace as it might remove/screw wrong parts and also you can better understand the module.
4. If you would like to be able to improve the module later on, **mark** the changes/additions you made so later on if the module gets updated you can merge/add those improvements to your module as well.